# css3 multiple background images fade in and out while moving

Tags: php, html, css

I have a map on a page where I have an image that I can move from X to Y as a still png image.

I would like to change this to having the still image become an animated image and then return to a still image.

This is what I have now in my CSS file and in my PHP file. How can I change the CSS or PHP file so that I don't see all the images? I want to create a 'walking' motion (maybe by showing one image after the other? then hiding the prior shown image?)

```css
div.animate-stills
{
  width: 13px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 5s 1;
  animation: mymove 5s 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vault/style_animate.css">
  <?php /* my php here */ ?>
  <style>
    /* ANY DIRECTION */
    @-webkit-keyframes mymove
    {
      from {top: <?php echo "$playerlocation_y"; ?>px; left: <?php echo "$playerlocation_x"; ?>px;}
      to {top: <?php echo "$move_y"; ?>px; left: <?php echo "$move_x"; ?>px;}
    }
    @keyframes mymove
    {
      from{top: <?php echo "$playerlocation_y"; ?>px; left: <?php echo "$playerlocation_x"; ?>px;}
      to{top: <?php echo "$move_y"; ?>px; left: <?php echo "$move_x"; ?>px;}
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <?php /* my php here */
echo '<div class="animate-stills" syle="position: absolute; top: ' . $playerlocation_y . 'px; left: ' . $playerlocation_x . 'px; background-image: url(' . $img_1 . '),url(' . $img_2 . '),url(' . $img_3 . '),url(' . $img_4 . '),url(' . $img_5 . '),url(' . $img_6 . '),url(' . $img_7 . '),url(' . $img_8 . '); background-size: contain; background-position: center center; width: 13px; height: 30px;"></div>';
  ?>
</body>
```

I have simplified the php so you can make some sense of it. all the $variables are declared and or taken from the database.

HTML outputs the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SKULLS AND BONES</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vault/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vault/style_animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vault/style_hex50.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
    <style>
       /* ANY DIRECTION */
       /* Chrome,Safari,Opera */
       @-webkit-keyframes mymove
        {
          from {top: 86px; left: 232px;}
          to {top: 86px; left: 284px;}
        }
        /* Default syntax */
        @keyframes mymove
        {
          from {top: 86px; left: 232px;}
          to {top: 86px; left: 284px;}
        }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="animate-stills" style="position: absolute; top: 86px; left: 232px; background-image: url(vault/images/alpha/player_male_1.png), url(vault/images/alpha/test_male02.png), url(vault/images/alpha/test_male03.png), url(vault/images/alpha/test_male04.png), url(vault/images/alpha/test_male05.png), url(vault/images/alpha/test_male06.png), url(vault/images/alpha/test_male07.png), url(vault/images/alpha/test_male08.png); background-size: contain; background-position: center center; width: 32px; height: 32px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have shortened the output for better reading.

Comment: Would be better if you just post the compiled HTML instead of PHP..

Comment: I could login from the machine and post the actual files as they are now?

Comment: I can't seem to post that as full snippet.

Comment: Just open your webpage in the browser to see the compiled HTML source

Comment: Added the compiled HTML source, shortened it for better reading.

Comment: looking at my output HTML I see @keyframes mymove that two top: px; are there. this is because the player moved and that got not set. I fixed this by adding the following code for both X and Y: if( $move_x == NULL) {    $move_x = $playerlocation_x;    }

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of fiddling arround and searching google more on the subject I found some solution. I had to make a few changes. Here is the CSS file.

```css
div.animate-movement
{
    background: url(images/alpha/MaleWalkingSheet128x30.png);
    width: 16px;
    height: 30px;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-animation: mymove 2.1s steps(8) 3;
    animation: mymove 2.1s steps(8) 3;
}
```

And here is some of the output from the php in the html file. I have placed this in the php file because the values are always changing.

```html
/* ANY DIRECTION */
/* Chrome,Safari,Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove
{
    from {top: 209px; left: 206px;}
    to {top: 250px; left: 232px;}
    from {background-position: 0px; }
    to {background-position: -128px; }             
}
/* Default syntax */
@keyframes mymove
{
    from {top: 209px; left: 206px;}
    to {top: 250px; left: 232px;}
    from {background-position: 0px; }
    to {background-position: -128px; }            
}

<div class="animate-movement"></div>
```

The only problem I now seem to have with this is that it sometimes looks like the image is 'warping' backward to where it was before ending the animation. I searched google for this and therefore I added: transform: translate3d(0,0,0); to the css file. apparantly that turns the animation over to the GPU?
The animation sometimes 'warps' any way to fix this?